# Disable notification sounds for email

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, email, notifications, audio, motorola-photon

Is it possible to disable the **notification sound** for emails while still keeping the notification light and status bar notification?

I'm interested in this setting for a Motorola Photon (Gingerbread).

Comment: If you can chose the notification sound for email separately, you could assign it an "empty" (silent) audio file.

Comment: @Izzy thanks for the suggestion. I was trying to figure out if that was possible but the only options I see in `Sound Settings` are for `Phone ringtone` and `Notification ringtone`. Maybe there is a setting somewhere else that I did not see but I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: You need to look in the Email application's settings, not the phone settings. Each app handles its notification sounds and settings independently.

Comment: And often there's also one sound called "Silent" (i.e. no sound), which would then match your requirements.